# How to get exact user sitting position latitude and longitude values in a room?

Tags: swift, mapkit, ios9, cllocationmanager, xcode7

I want get exact user sitting position latitude and longitude values in a room or building. I am getting user location latitude and longitude values through CLLocationManager but not exactly showing. Is any possibility through get user exact building latitude and longitude values.

Thanks
Laxman

Answer (score 0):

GPS precision is usually at best 10m, so you cannot expect to obtain positions with better precision than that, which is not usually enough for positioning within a building. Besides, if your user is not using GPS, you will get network-based positioning data which has yet lower precision.

I don't think you can use CLLocationManager or any other out-of-the-box positioning service for that.

Technologies exist that can be used to locate a phone within a building based on other sensor data (eg. https://en.situm.es/solutions.php), that perhaps you could apply.

There are also ways to improve GPS precision outdoors (eg. https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wide_Area_Augmentation_System) depending on where you live. It all depends on your application.

Comment: Can you send any useful links or any examples

Comment: No, sorry. My point is that your code is possibly ok, but the technology won't allow for more precise latitude and longitude values unless you use some other technology (instead of the GPS + network based position that you are currently using).